# yarn install --latest all packages? (I don't care about breaking changes)

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

How do you force yarn to ignore your package.json version ranges/carets and install the very latest stable version of all packages?

I can do `yarn add packagename@latest` one by one for all of them, but I'd love to do it in one shot, regardless of whether there are breaking changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`yarn upgrade`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade/).

Below will help you update to `latest` for all packages and update `yarn.lock`:

```
yarn upgrade --force --latest
```

If you don't want to update the lock file, you can do the following instead:

```
yarn upgrade --force --latest --no-lockfile
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me for whatever reason. When I run `yarn outdated` all the packages are 2 or 3 major versions behind.

Comment: The docs suggest `--latest` should work: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade/#toc-yarn-upgrade-package-latest-l-caret-tilde-exact-pattern

Comment: The way I see it - using the force ignores what you have in the `node_modules`. Cleaner in a way as you exactly know all the latest are downloaded and put in place.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what I tried, I couldn't get yarn to upgrade all the packages to the latest major versions.

install or upgrade with `--force --latest` didn't work.

This did:

`yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`

Then press `a` to select all and enter to upgrade to the latest.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade-interactive/

Comment: this doesn't even list all my dependencies as options.  junk tool.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you run older yarn or more modern yarn, this is what I typically use.

For older yarn (version 1.x):

```
yarn upgrade --latest --ignore-engines
```

For modern yarn:

```
yarn up '*'
```